# querying on deep jsonb datatype in postgres sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have user table with email, firstname, lastname and addresses (JSONB) datatypes.
Here is the record in my table:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstname": "praneeth",
        "lastname": "T",
        "email": "praneeth12@gmail.com",
        "addresses": [
            {
                "city": "Bengaluru",
                "state": "Karnataka"
            },
            {
                "city": "Hyderabad",
                "state": "Telangana"
            },
            {
                "city": "Mysore",
                "state": "Karnataka"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I query on **city** in node sequelize.
Below is the code what I tried:

```
 var user2 =  await db.User.findAll({
    where: {
      addresses: {
        '$contains': { city: "Hyderabad" }
      }
    }
  })
```

But not getting results. Can anybody help me out of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
where: {
  addresses: {
    $contains: [{
      city: 'Bengaluru'
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: While your code may correct as answer But Elaborating what your code does, It can improve the quality of your answer. Checkout the Article : [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)